# How do i enforce indexes when Using Order by clause?

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, sql-order-by

`where` clause and `order by` clause are different then Oracle didn't identify the indexing

```
INNER JOIN ORG_ACCOUNTING_PERIODS p
 ON p.ORG_ROADMARK = c.ORG_ROADMARK
 AND p.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = c.SERVICE_PERIOD
        where ( c.ORG_ROADMARK =:roadMark )
        and c.ORG_ROADMARK = c.move_road 
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATETIME;
```

Comment: We'd need to know a lot more about your tables, indexes, statistics etc. to help.

Answer (score 0):

when using index and order by that order by should be sub set of where clause, because indexes directly applied to where clause.

So add --->

```
INNER JOIN ORG_ACCOUNTING_PERIODS p ON p.ORG_ROADMARK = c.ORG_ROADMARK AND p.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = c.SERVICE_PERIOD
        where ( c.ORG_ROADMARK =:roadMark )
        and c.ORG_ROADMARK = c.move_road         
        and c.EVENT_DATETIME between :eventFrom AND :eventTo
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATETIME ;

create index --> `CREATE INDEX "CARHIRE_EVENTS_IX" ON "CARHIRE_EVENTS" ("EVENT_DATETIME", "MOVE_ROAD", "ORG_ROADMARK") ;`
```